# Fedora Svr route issue: destination and gateway are wrong (swapped). How can I set them correctly?

Tags: fedora

I am trying to setup Fedora Server 25 to run NextCloud, but am having trouble with eth0. I set a static IP and have full LAN connectivity, but there is an issue with my route: **the gateway is set to 0.0.0.0 instead of 192.168.1.1 and the destination is set to 192.168.1.1 instead of * (or 0.0.0.0)**. It's worth mentioning that if I run `ifdown eth0` and `ifup etho0` the VM gets an IP via DCHP and all routing works, but I must have a static IP for this server.

Try as I may, I cannot figure out how to change this. Here is my `ifconfig` and `netstat -nr`:

```
[root@FedoraSvr25.local]# ifconfig eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.36  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fea9:f1bf  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:a9:f1:bf  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 40110  bytes 3180764 (3.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14500  bytes 5139318 (4.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 686  bytes 772335 (754.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 686  bytes 772335 (754.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    [root@FedoraSvr.local]# netstat -nr 
Kernel IP routing table Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags  MSS Window  irtt Iface
                         192.168.1.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Comment: What is your configuration file, specifically IPADDR PREFIX and GATEWAY?      While you are at it,  I don't recommend .local TLD as it conflicts with mDNS use.   .test has no conflicts if you do not have a publicly registered domain name.

Comment: Thank you, John. I just discovered a typo in my `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` NIC config: it was `ifcGf-eth0` when instead of `ifcfg-eth0`! Fixing that resolved my issue. WOW, the little stuff, right!? :)

Comment: For the TLD conflict with mDNS issue, do you mean the `.local` at the end of my hostname?

Comment: Yup.  Please answer your own question and accept it to document.   And yes the .local  top level domain is a conflict.  Use a domain you have from a public registrar,  or  .test   which will not be registered to anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered a typo in my `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` NIC config: it was **ifcGf-eth0** when it should be `ifcfg-eth0`! Fixing that resolved my issue.